# How to prevent styles from reaching into div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an interesting situation I'm trying to find a solution to.

There is a script that needs to be included that builds an HTML element on the page. The issue is that there are global defaults CSS styles that are interacting with this built element and preventing it from functioning.

So our ".core-design form" has a property that is being applied to this built element's form. None of our style needs to be used, as the script is calling in its own stylesheet.

Is there a way to prevent the div containing this element from getting any and all styles from our .core-design?

Edit: To add some clarity as to specifics.

1) The core-design class is attached to every page across many sites.

2) The sub-elements being targeted are the element names, not classes.

3) I am able to add styling to target the div around the generated content, but want to avoid modifying .core-design stylesheet due to its scope.

4) The generated content pulls in its own stylesheet.

5) I have no control over the content being pulled in, and it may change in the future.

6) [Codepen of the situation I am currently in](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzryRr)

```css
body {
  // the .core-design is applied here which contains the form styles.
}
form {
  min-height:300px;
  min-width:300px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="controlled">
    <div class="generated">
      <form>
        <!--
        I need to prevent this form/generated div from inheriting any styles. Including any other sub-components inside of it. The only item I 'control' is the wrapping div.
        -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just remove that class

Comment: Post your CSS and HTML for better/faster answers. Or an MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: or give it a different classname

Comment: @sorayadragon you mean an MCVE

Comment: @BillGates That I do.

Comment: @sorayadragon Thanks for the link! I'm not too frequent around here, so assistance is greatly appreciated. I updated the post with what information will hopefully be enough to show the situation I'm in.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1:

Simple, it is all about CSS selector.

Add a class called `ignore-this` to the form you want to be ignored.

Then update the global css to have `form:not(.ignore-this)`.

#### Example below, CSS applied to 1st form but skip the 2nd form.

```css
.core-design form:not(.ignore-this) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="core-design">
  <form>
    form 111111
  </form>
  <form class="ignore-this">
    form 222222
  </form>
</div>
```

#### Solution 2 (updated)

since you have no control over the `core-design` css, what you could do is to add a css rule like the following and add the class name to the form you want to reset CSS style:

```
form.ignore-this{
  all: unset;
}
```

> #### The CSS `all` shorthand property resets all properties, apart from unicode-bidi and direction, to their initial or inherited value.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all
>
> [image]

```css
.core-design form {
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

form.ignore-this{
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="core-design">
  <form>
    form 111111
  </form>
  <form class="ignore-this">
    form 222222
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The form that I want to ignore is inside of a javascript generated piece of content. I have no access to change what is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way. You can use the `all` CSS property. More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all.

There's no support for IE :(, but there are polyfills available.

Comment: Unfortunately any solution I come up with must support all major browsers, including IE. It is starting to look like I'm going to have to dig into the generated content, find all instances where default styles are being applied, and over-write them. *sigh*

Comment: @OrionSuperman check this library https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-initial it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

This should reset all styles:

```
div.className * { 

     all: initial; 
     all: unset; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear but i think you are having css override issues.
If you know the names of the classes and ids the div  has you can change you ids and class names of the core-design so they wouldnt be the same.
Like:
if you have a class named .navi and the div contains .navi css will try to either override that of the div or that of the core depends.
Make sure your cores class and id names are unique from that of the div

Comment: Not so much an override, but close. There are global minimal settings for all elements inside of .core-design for consistency across all pages and sites.

The generated content doesn't have anything specifying form min-width for example, so the global .core-design is being applied. Due to the generated content being inside the scope of the .core-design, it is inheriting some of the defaults.